# Reached end of document without finding - using mod_pagespeed

Tags: customization

I'm getting this error repeatedly in my error.log:

```
[Wed Dec 29 13:46:37 2010] [error] [mod_pagespeed 0.9.11.5-293] http://marcandkatie.co.za/index.php:1: Reached end of document without finding <body>
```

And I believe it's caused my site todo this when I go to the admin:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4666733 bytes) in /home/marc_and_katie/marcandkatie.co.za/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 849
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please specify the wordpress version you use on that host. I smell you're hitting a memory leak in wp-db.php. This can be caused by data in the database. Are you able to get a backtrace of the error logged?

Answer (score 1):

So I started going thru plugins and my Mailchimp plugin seemed to be the issue as I can tell so far. I'm no longer getting any errors.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

this error is caused because of wp-cache plugin, not sure but clear your cache from, the error might go

Comment: The problem is I can't even clear the sites cache because I get that second error when I try to go to my admin. So I don't have access to the plugin settings to clear the cache.

Comment: i think you need to give 777 permission to your wp-content folder, or try to copy paste db.php from plugins/wp-cache/wp-content directory from cpanel

Comment: to the folder and the files and folders within it? or just that folder?

EDIT: I'm using wp-super-cache... does that make any difference? also what file am i copying cause the directory you mentioned doesn't exist.

Comment: see the same error i was getting but i was using w3-total cache plugin, these both plugins are almost same, i solved this error just by copy pasting files, i ll xplain you
navigate to wp-content/plugin/wp-super-cache/wp-content/

here you ll find db.php file, just copy that and paste it into wordpress/wp-content
see if this works :)

Comment: there wasn't a wp-content folder inside of the wp-super-cache folder so there's no db.php file to copy. right now i just renamed the plugin so it wouldn't be active and i can login now. any other thoughts?

Comment: do you think i should just switch over to w3-total cache plugin instead?

Comment: yaa you should, cause mostly everyone uses that plugin, but before installing this, deactivate and delete this plugin

Comment: Great I'll do that. The main reason I was using a cache plugin is because php scripts were running so much memory on the server that I couldn't load admin pages.

Comment: Arg. I installed w3 total and i got the same issue as originated and even when i copy the db.php it still doesn't work... any other thoughts?

Comment: just copy paste the exact error

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8729995 bytes) in /home/marc_and_katie/marcandkatie.co.za/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 787

Comment: try adding this line to .htaccess file

`php_value memory_limit "16M"`
16 is 16 MB
you can change the 16 to fit to your choice

Comment: this is your perfect answer
http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/02/17/wordpress-error-fix-increase-php-memory-for-cachephp/

Comment: shame... it made it worse. now i undid what that post said and i'm getting this every where: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4717706 bytes) in /home/marc_and_katie/marcandkatie.co.za/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 849

Comment: try change the MB here it is showing 47 mb, you keep 60 MB and then try

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something in your WordPress installation exhausts available resources.

It is impossible to even guess from this much information, first step would be to disable all plugins and troubleshoot from there. Since you don't have access to admin see [How to deactivate all plugins when not able to access the administrative menus?](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F)

Answer (score -1):

Just an FYI the error you're getting from mod_pagespeed is AFTER the php error.

Delete the plugin completely, and then re-install the w3-total-cache plugin, and then run a compatibility check.. see if it says anything about permissions or ownership.

Comment: nope just this: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8729995 bytes) in /home/marc_and_katie/marcandkatie.co.za/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 787

Comment: this happens even when you're in the admin screens? or just the home page? and is this 3.0.4 ?

Comment: Now it's happening nearly everywhere. Yes, it's 3.0.4. This is just getting annoying now.